# Solidifying SVG remains 2 dimensional

Tags: path, svg

I am attempting to import a basic SVG enclosed path into Blender (2.8) and extrude it so that it becomes a solid. From other website resources, it seems that the best way to do that is to import the SVG, convert it to a mesh, and then solidify it. However, when I apply solidify to the mesh the object still appears completely flat. For larger values of solidify, what looks like a second mesh starts to warp. With smaller thickness values, it appears that a clone of the mesh is superimposed on it (but still no thickness).

Thanks for your help in advance; I am definitely a beginner.

Here's the imported SVG
[image: Here's the imported SVG]

Here's the result of solidify
[image: Here's the result of solidify]

Here's from another angle showing the flatness
[image: Here's from another angle showing the flatness]

Comment: Hello :). The Solidify modifier says: "Faces needed for useful output". That's gotta be a hint :).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @JachymMichal I definitely did not realize there was that warning.

Comment: And next time change the viewoport background color or select your mesh, to make it more visible, dealing with wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment, I appeared to figure it out. Selected the mesh, went to edit mode, selected all vertices, press F to create a face, then solidified.